# Use local closure?

Tags: swift

It has been pointed out to me that there is a better way to write this code not using a local closure. How can I do this? Switch images on click.

```
@IBAction func btnMuteMicPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    publisher.publishAudio.toggle()

    let buttonImage: UIImage  = {
        if !publisher.publishAudio {
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "group3-1")
        } else {
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "group3")
        }
    }()

    btnMuteMic.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's a question for the person who made that claim? I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be shorten to,

```
@IBAction func btnMuteMicPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    publisher.publishAudio.toggle()
    let buttonImage = !publisher.publishAudio ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "group3-1") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "group3")
    btnMuteMic.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
}
```

I don't think `closure` to get `buttonImage` is required here. This definitely not mean that your code is erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

Closure definitely can be dropped here:

```
@IBAction func btnMuteMicPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    publisher.publishAudio.toggle()

    let buttonImage: UIImage
    if !publisher.publishAudio {
        buttonImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "group3-1")
    } else {
        buttonImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "group3")
    }

    btnMuteMic.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
}
```

But there's nothing inherently wrong with the old way of initialising.